# Why sweetalert2 dialog does not work under livewire component template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, sweetalert2

I added sweetalert2 ( version 11.1.5 ) into my Laravel 8 / livewire 2.5 / alpinejs 3 / tailwindcss: 2.2 app with

```
npm install sweetalert2
```

command

and importing and testing in resources/js/app.js I see next message :

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();

require('@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.min.js');

import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
window.Swal = Swal;
  
Swal.fire('Test!', 'Hello test message','success');
```

But I got

```
 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'fire' of undefined
```

error in my livewire component template resources/views/livewire/admin/facilities/container.blade.php :

```
<div >

    <div class="editor_listing_wrapper_bix_width" x-data="adminFacilitiesComponent()"
         x-init="[onAdminFacilitiesComponentInit() ]">

          ...
    </div>

</div>

<script>

    function adminFacilitiesComponent() {
        return {

            onAdminFacilitiesComponentInit: function (component) {
                console.log('window.Swal::') 
                console.log(window.Swal)     // I see Undefined here

                window.Swal.fire('Hello world!') // this line raise error!

            },

        }
    } // function adminFacilitiesComponent() {

</script>
```

Why error and how it can be fixed ?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you install `'es6-promise'` ? Maybe the error comes from there

Comment: No es6-promise reference in my package.json. Have I to install it with  npp add es6-promise command ?

Comment: Install it with the command `npm i es6-promise`. Then, add line `import 'es6-promise/auto'` before `import Swal from 'sweetalert2';`

Comment: you shouldn't npm run dev after install package?

Comment: No, it did not help : window.Swal is still  undefined